# C++ reading from file and adding elements to string vector

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

I have a String vector

```
std::vector<string> userList;
```

I would like to read from "password.txt" that is arranged like:

1. name1
2. password1
3. (blank line)
4. name2
5. password2

how do I take the names on line 1 + 3C and add them to the userList vector

`FILE * file;`

```
    file = fopen("password.txt" , "w+");
```

Comment: Please post sample input, the code you have tried, and explain what you mean by "line 1 + 3C".

Comment: Use an `ifstream` instead of a `FILE *`.

Comment: I don't know what "line 1 + 3C" means. It's also not clear how you want to store the contents of the file. Do you want one entry per user in `userList` or multiple entries? Also, be aware that opening the input file in mode "w+" destroys the contents of the file. I think you want mode "r".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ifstream` insead of `fopen` which comes from c.

```
ifstream reader();
reader.open("password.txt");
```

Now use `getline` to read lines from the file.
Every third line is a username, so you can skip all other lines:

```
string line;
int i = 3;
while(getline(reader,line)){
   if(i == 3){
       userList.push_back(line);
       i = 0;
   }else{
       i++;
   }
}
```

Or you use mod operator to get every third line:

```
string line;
int i = 0;
while(getline(reader,line)){
   if(i % 3 == 0){
       userList.push_back(line);
   }
   i++;
}
```